# Unable to find cause of "Attribute value must be constant" error

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am new to programming and trying to create an app for food delivery using android studio and have been following this [guide](https://youtu.be/SfiDWNZQk6M?si=5KFXWWadigpkN8jW).

However, I got stuck about 7 minutes in when I started receiving the error message "Attribute value must be constant" on the lines:
`@BindView(R.id.recycler_products)`
`@BindView(R.id.mainLayout)`
`@BindView(R.id.badge)`

Perhaps I incorrectly copied the code but after going through the video multiple times I still haven't been able to find the source.

This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panel"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="16"
        android:background="#F7CF9C"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_arrow_back_ios_new_24"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
            android:layout_weight="11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/products"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/abraham"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
        
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/btncart"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cartButton"
                android:src="@drawable/baseline_shopping_cart_checkout_24"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <com.nex3z.notificationbadge.NotificationBadge
                android:id="@+id/badge"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_ToRightOf="@id/cartButton"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/cartButton"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                app:nbMaxTextLength="2" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_products"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.carttest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.nex3z.notificationbadge.NotificationBadge;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.recycler_products)
    RecyclerView recyclerProducts;
    @BindView(R.id.mainLayout)
    RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.badge)
    NotificationBadge badge;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }
}
```

I tried using ChatGPT and CoPilot in an attempt to find the cause of the issue but it hasn't been successful.

I tried adding to MainActivity.java

```
    private static final int RECYCLER_VIEW_ID = R.id.recycler_products;
    private static final int MAIN_LAYOUT_ID = R.id.mainLayout;
    private static final int BADGE_ID = R.id.badge;
```

and
`ButterKnife.bind(this);`

However both of them didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't seem to understand what you mean by viewbinding. When using R2 instead of R I receive the error message "Cannot resolve symbol 'R2'". As I said I am new to programming and would highly appreciate a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: Can you please explain how is this question related to Firebase?